# OpenCV supported camera types

Tags: opencv, camera

I am using opencv 2.4.10 and am wondering if I hook up a usb 2.0 camera that uses a 10 bit analog to digital converter and has a resolution of 1328 x 1048, does openCV support that type of camera? If it does, how will it store the pixel information? (I have not purchased the camera yet and would buy a different one if the software won't work with it, so I can't just go test it myself).

Answer (score 0):

clearly I didn't google well enough

https://web.archive.org/web/20120815172655/http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS/

list hasn't been updated for a while though